# Which datastructure to use in big values?

Tags: java, text, data-structures, mapreduce, bitset

I am writting a programme in mapreduce. I need to save a big value for each key. In detail for each id(key), I want to save a value that consists of large numbers. I used numbers from 1 to 100000000. for example:

```
id       value
1        1,3,9,23,56,345,.......,10000000000
2        6,8,45,321,876,.........,98760000876
.
.
.
100000000   1,2,6.83,90,126,567,.......,7632786765643
```

In each iteration the amount of numbers in each value increases. Firstly, I choose Text type for value, but in the results I saw that shuffle size became very big and I couldn't get answer. Then i choosed `BitSet` Type but the process of BitSet was very slow.I don't know which data structure, I can use that can provide me with size and process speed.Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: @AurA: Cn BigInteger save a lot of numbers? for each number, how much space does it need? Is it fast?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can associate a `List` for each key. So you can use a `Map` wich associates an ID to a List of numbers : `Map<Integer, List<Long>>`

Comment: Which one is better? Array of longs or list of longs?

Comment: Using array in Java is a bad idea. You can use an `ArrayList` instead (random access in O(1)). But if you want to keep the order in your numbers, use a `LinkedList` instead.

Comment: list is better or set?

Comment: Why array is a bad idea? which advantages does ArrayList have that array doesn't?

Comment: An array is a static structure : u can't change its size "on the fly" easily. An `ArrayList` is an object where if you add elements its size will grow automatically. Moreover, you have many methods on an `ArrayList` to manipulate it, like `contains()`, `remove()`, ...

Answer (score 0):

in Java the int data type is a 32-bit signed integer. It has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 which is not enough in your case. If you have a 64-bit machine, you can use 'int' type.

Otherwise, you can use a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

for me the appropriate data structure is a:

```
Map<Integer, List<BigInteger>>
```

Comment: Is biginteger better than bitset? is it fast?

Comment: Regular operations on BigInteger (add, substract, multiply, divide) is of course slower than corresponding basic types, due to the large size it uses in memory. BigInteger are also immutable. So every operation will create a new instance, which is costful regarding the number of operations you have to do.

Comment: Due to the size of numbers you want to manipulate, I will consider moving from a 32-bit to a 64-bit machine where you could simply use 'int' to represent numbers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.